# Android kill process from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, usb, broadcastreceiver, kill-process

Hi i'm looking to kill an activity in my application when the usb is disconnected i have a broadcast receiver and all set up and working fine

```
public class USBOff extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, SdcardOff.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
    finish();
    }
 }
```

This code however tells me that the finish method and startActivity methods need to be created? why is this not working thank you for any help with my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity` is a Context method, not a BroadcastReceiver method. `finish` is an Activity method. Try this:

`context.startActivity(intent1);`

You can't call `finish` from a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an interexting method : 
Manfest :

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
<action android:name="com.gr.app.KILLSELF" />
```

receiver code :

```
Intent intentInterface = new Intent("com.gr.app.KILLSELF");
mContext.startActivity(intentInterface);
```

activity onCreate part :

```
if (intent.getAction().compareTo("com.gr.app.KILLSELF") == 0) {
        finish();
    };
```

It will not work in such configuration if you may have many instancesof activity (string android:launchMode="singleInstance" is a problem for you),

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Simple Logic :

If you dont want to kill the activity then do not use finish() And if you want to kill the activity then you should have to call finish();

So remove the finish(); from code and try it out.
Enjoy.